# discord.py module how do i remove the command text afterwards?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

```
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

import secrets
from time import sleep

discordBot = Bot(command_prefix = ".")

listStrings = ['add a reaction', 'adnd']

@discordBot.event
async def on_read():
    print('Client logged in')


@discordBot.command()
async def s(*args):
        return await discordBot.say (" ".join(args))

@discordBot.command()
async def close():
    quit()


discordBot.run(secrets.token)
```

I wanted to say ".s (text)" and that the bot says the text(works already) but deletes your message, how can i do this? i got the part working of on_message:

```
@discordbot.event
async def on_message(message):
    await discordBot.delete_message(message)
```

What is the best way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry you haven't got an answer for 26 days. If you are still looking for an answer, I hope I can provide some help. So I ran your code, and the bot ran the command, my message deleted, then the bot's message also deleted. One way to fix this is to provide an **if** statement which means the bot only deletes the message if the author is **not** a bot.

```
@test_bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if not (message.author).bot:
        await test_bot.delete_message(message)
    await test_bot.process_commands(message)
```

Another way to remove only messages that are the commands is to use another **if** statement. The following code is specific, so you only delete commands, not just all user's messages if they aren't a bot. The following code uses `message.content` which returns the message as a string.

```
@test_bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('.s'):
        await test_bot.delete_message(message)
    await test_bot.process_commands(message)
```